# cannot evaluating my summaries with pyrouge

Tags: python

i want to evaluate my summaries by pyrouge. pyrouge is present [here](https://github.com/bheinzerling/pyrouge). pyrouge is a python wrapper for the ROUGE summarization evaluation package.
i executed these commands in sequence, successfully:

```
git clone https://github.com/bheinzerling/pyrouge
cd pyrouge
python setup.py install
pyrouge_set_rouge_path /absolute/path/to/ROUGE-1.5.5/directory
python -m pyrouge.test
```

my problem is when i want to use pyrouge for evaluating my summaries. i wrote these commands:

```
from pyrouge import Rouge155
r = Rouge155()
r.system_dir = "/home/afsharizadeh/Desktop/summarization/summarization_dataset/DUC_2007/2007/all_sum/system_sum/"
r.model_dir = "/home/afsharizadeh/Desktop/summarization/summarization_dataset/DUC_2007/2007/all_sum/ref_sum/"
r.system_filename_pattern = 'sum.(\d+).txt'
r.model_filename_pattern = 'sum.[A-Z].#ID#.txt'

output = r.convert_and_evaluate()
print(output)
output_dict = r.output_to_dict(output)
```

but i receive this error:

```
<pre>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-8-b3bc5a66e7f0> in <module>()
      6 r.model_filename_pattern = 'sum.[A-Z].#ID#.txt'
      7 
----> 8 output = r.convert_and_evaluate()
      9 print(output)
     10 output_dict = r.output_to_dict(output)

/home/afsharizadeh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyrouge/Rouge155.py in convert_and_evaluate(self, system_id, split_sentences, rouge_args)
    358         if split_sentences:
    359             self.split_sentences()
--> 360         self.__write_summaries()
    361         rouge_output = self.evaluate(system_id, rouge_args)
    362         return rouge_output

/home/afsharizadeh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyrouge/Rouge155.py in __write_summaries(self)
    487     def __write_summaries(self):
    488         self.log.info("Writing summaries.")
--> 489         self.__process_summaries(self.convert_summaries_to_rouge_format)
    490 
    491     @staticmethod

/home/afsharizadeh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyrouge/Rouge155.py in __process_summaries(self, process_func)
    481             "model files to {}.".format(new_system_dir, new_model_dir))
    482         process_func(self._system_dir, new_system_dir)
--> 483         process_func(self._model_dir, new_model_dir)
    484         self._system_dir = new_system_dir
    485         self._model_dir = new_model_dir

/home/afsharizadeh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyrouge/Rouge155.py in convert_summaries_to_rouge_format(input_dir, output_dir)
    200         """
    201         DirectoryProcessor.process(
--> 202             input_dir, output_dir, Rouge155.convert_text_to_rouge_format)
    203 
    204     @staticmethod

/home/afsharizadeh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyrouge/utils/file_utils.py in process(input_dir, output_dir, function)
     27             input_file = os.path.join(input_dir, input_file_name)
     28             with codecs.open(input_file, "r", encoding="UTF-8") as f:
---> 29                 input_string = f.read()
     30             output_string = function(input_string)
     31             output_file = os.path.join(output_dir, input_file_name)

/home/afsharizadeh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/codecs.py in read(self, size)
    696     def read(self, size=-1):
    697 
--> 698         return self.reader.read(size)
    699 
    700     def readline(self, size=None):

/home/afsharizadeh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/codecs.py in read(self, size, chars, firstline)
    499                 break
    500             try:
--> 501                 newchars, decodedbytes = self.decode(data, self.errors)
    502             except UnicodeDecodeError as exc:
    503                 if firstline:

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 947: invalid continuation byte
</pre>
```

what should i do?

Comment: There are a lot of `encoding='utf-8')` in the source. You can try to check if the file is UTF-8 or convert it to UTF-8 if needed. There should be plenty of tools for converting online

Comment: https://github.com/andersjo/pyrouge/blob/master/pyrouge/rouge.py

Comment: https://www.motobit.com/util/charset-codepage-conversion.asp first google attempt